# Router Link Active not working in the below scenario, is their any alternate way to activate button dynamically?

Tags: css, angular, typescript

HTML code

```
<div class="card-header">
  <h5>Refill by date</h5>
  <div class="card-header-right">
    <nav class="navbar bg-faded ">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item" routerLinkActive="active">
          <button (click)="setView('branch'); getFranchiseRefillsByDateAndBranch()" class="btn btn-mini btn-bg-c-blue btn-outline-default btn-round btn-action">
          <i class="icofont icofont-ui-check"> By branch</i>
          </button>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item" routerLinkActive="active">
          <button (click)="setView('product'); getFranchiseRefillsByDateAndProduct()" class="btn btn-mini btn-bg-c-blue btn-outline-default btn-round btn-action">
          <i class="icofont icofont-ui-check"> By product</i>
          </button>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item" routerLinkActive="active">
          <button (click)="setView('list'); getFranchiseRefillsByDateAndList()" class="btn btn-mini btn-bg-c-blue btn-outline-default btn-round btn-action">
          <i class="icofont icofont-ui-check"> Refill list</i>
          </button>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

part of TS code

```
  getFranchiseRefillsByDateAndBranch() {
    this.items = [];
    var hrchyIds = this.jwtHelperService.getFRefillHrchyIds();
    var ym = this.localStorage.retrieve('frym');
    if (hrchyIds) {
      this.refillService.getFranchiseRefillsByDateAndYear(hrchyIds, ym, "branch", this.page, this.rec).subscribe(val => {
        this.items = val;
      });
    }
  }
```

CSS code

```
.nav-item.active button i{
    color: #3D94CD !important;
}
```

I am trying to change color of active button using router link active but this method does not work in this case, is their any alternate way of adding class dynamically, based on current click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

routerLinkActive works if there was a routerLink on this element.

Keep `currentActiveItem` variable in ts file. Set some default value say "branch"

```
currentActiveItem : string = "branch"
```

Change value of this variable in `setView` function.

And additionally also use ngClass as following on correspondiong li elements.

```
[ngClass]="{'active' : currentActiveItem == 'branch'}"
[ngClass]="{'active' : currentActiveItem == 'product'}"
[ngClass]="{'active' : currentActiveItem == 'list'}"
```